# How to set security/Authorisation Token in Post request of Rest Assured using selenium

Tags: rest-assured

Please suggest how i can set Security token for below code

RestAssured.baseURI ="http://qa.bridge2capital.com";
      RestAssured.port = 9099;

```
  RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();     
  JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();

  requestParams.put("UserName", "10111");
  requestParams.put("Password", "123568");

  request.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
  request.body(requestParams.toString());
  Response response = request.post("/entrepreneur/consolidatedEodTrigger");

  int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
  Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, "200");
  String successCode = response.jsonPath().get("SuccessCode");
  Assert.assertEquals( "Correct Success code was returned", successCode, "OPERATION_SUCCESS");
```

Comment: What is your authorization method? Authorization header? Cookie? Something else?

Comment: @aBnormaLz   Need to work for Basic authorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your answer you should try

```
RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();     
JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();

requestParams.put("UserName", "10111");
requestParams.put("Password", "123568");

request.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.header("Authorization", "Basic " + base64encodedToken); //This is the important line
request.body(requestParams.toString());
Response response = request.post("/entrepreneur/consolidatedEodTrigger");

int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, "200");
String successCode = response.jsonPath().get("SuccessCode");
Assert.assertEquals( "Correct Success code was returned", successCode, "OPERATION_SUCCESS");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to set basic token:

```
request.header("Authorization", "Basic " + yourToken);
```

Comment: please suggest where i put this ?